# How to write unit test for Program and Startup cs file for ASP.NET Core Web API app

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

Is there any ways to write unit test for `Program` cs file for ASP.NET Core Web API and similarly for `startup` class, just to show more code coverage for the entire app? It's shows 0% coverage for now.

[image]

Comment: That isn't something you need to test. Covering it just so that your numbers are 100% provides no value. Write the rest of the application and test that code.

Comment: You can call `Main` just like any other method, whether there's any value in doing so is up to you.  In order to ensure the application starts up properly is typically done by integration tests or smoke tests.

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, could you share some code article on this. Appreciate @!

Comment: There is nothing really to unit test here. If the whole application really does what it should is an e2e or smoke test. Nothing you would do in a unit test.

Comment: ok Oliver, any code sample you can share for e2e/smoke which covers program and startup file test. Appreciate for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

you can extract the configuration out in separate calls and expose them into func<> which is you are custom created and write the unit test for them .
TIt is not recommended to test the framework code.
you should do testing for your code only not for the framework.
I hope you get the point correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Priyanshu. I get the point, but do you mind to share bit code as well.