# how to combine multiple assertion using FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, xunit, fluent-assertions

I came to know that through `FluentAssertions` library we can combine multiple assertion in a single like. Just want to know if below 2 assert can be combined in a single line?

```
        // Act 
        IActionResult actionResult = controller.Update();

        // Assert
        ((ObjectResult)actionResult).StatusCode.Should().Be(200);
        ((ObjectResult)actionResult).Value.Should().BeEquivalentTo("updated");
```

Comment: You can chain validations on a single property like `statusCode.Should().BeGreaterOrEqualTo(200).And.BeLessOrEqualTo(206);` but I don't think you can chain validation for multiple properties on a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the built-in assertions you can compare `actionResult` against an anonymous object.

```cs
IActionResult actionResult = new ObjectResult("updated")
{
    StatusCode = 200
};

var expected = new
{
    StatusCode = 200,
    Value = "updated"
};

actionResult.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

For you're specific case you can install [`FluentAssertions.AspNetCore.Mvc`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions.AspNetCore.Mvc/), which lets you write

```cs
actionResult.Should().BeObjectResult()
    .WithStatusCode(200)
    .WithValue("updated");
```

If you're using `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` and not `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`
there's

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions.Mvc3/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions.Mvc4/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions.Mvc5/

Comment: Appreciate and Thanks for this awesome tip. :) I have other question, would you mind have a look there  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721518/how-to-write-unit-test-for-program-and-startup-cs-file-for-asp-net-core-web-api